# Using appsettings.json in .Net 6 Worker service

Tags: c#, worker, .net-6.0

Is I wanted to add a singleton service that is dependent on appsettings.

How would I do this in the .Net 6 worker service startup?

```
using AutoMapper;

var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        services.AddSingleton<IOrderNumberGenerator, OrderNumberGenerator>();

        services.AddSingleton(new ServiceIwantToCall(<--I need too use apsettings here-->));
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: Is this issue still outstanding? Has my answer not solved your problem?

Comment: It did solve it :D thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you're trying to register an instance of `ServiceIwantToCall`. You can instead register a factory method to resolve one, and once it's resolved it will be a singleton. For example, this anonymous method:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => { 
    // resolve the configuration provider from the container
    IConfiguration config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

    // get the config value and instantiate a ServiceIwantToCall
    // return the instantiated service
    string someValue = config["myValueKey"];
    return new ServiceIwantToCall(someValue);
});
```